# Using encryption/hashing to create a secure login

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, cryptography, authentication

I am creating a login for an encrypted chat application which retrieves login information from a MySQL database. I have got to the point where I feel pretty confident that (to the best of my knowledge) it is relatively secure. I am trying to learn so feel free to criticize!

```
import hashlib
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

chat = Tk() #Api I am using to create the GUI for the application

#Connect to MySQL database
try:
    loginFRetrieve = open("LK.bin", "rb") #Retrieving Encryption key from file
    retrivedKey =  loginFRetrieve.read()
    loginFRetrieve.close()

    loginFRetrieve = open("LC.bin", "rb") #Retrieving MySQL server login credentials
    retrivedLC = loginFRetrieve.read()
    loginFRetrieve.close()

    cipher = Fernet(retrivedKey)
    retrivedLC = cipher.decrypt(retrivedLC) #Decrypting server login data from file
    retrivedLC = retrivedLC.decode('utf-8')
    lC = retrivedLC.split()

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=lC[0],user=lC[1],passwd=lC[2],database=lC[3])
    del(lC)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    chat.withdraw()
    messagebox.showerror("Database Error", "Failed to connect to database")
    exit()



mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#hashPass hashes and returns a string of characters using SHA-256 algorithm
def hashPass(hP):
    shaSignature = \
        hashlib.sha256(hP.encode()).hexdigest()
    return shaSignature

#userExists checks a database too see if username exists in the database
def userExists(userName):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE username = '%s'" % userName)
    userResult = mycursor.fetchall()
    if userResult:
        return True
    return False

#Creates a new user in the connected SQL database.
def newUser(nU, nP):
    if userExists(nU) == False:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE username = '%s'" % nU)
        mycursor.fetchall()
        r = hashPass(nP)
        sql = "INSERT INTO logins(username, passwordhash) VALUES(%s,%s)"
        val = (nU, r)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        chat.title(string="User created")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("User Creation Error", "User already exists")

#Checks the connected SQL database for an existing user.
def existingUser(uN, pW):
    if userN.get() != "":
        if userExists(uN) == True:
            encryptedPass = hashPass(pW)
            mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logins")
            passResult = mycursor.fetchall()
            for row in passResult:
                if row[1] == uN and row[2] == encryptedPass:
                    chat.title(string="Login Successful!")
                elif row[1] == uN and row[2] != encryptedPass:
                    messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Password does not match our records")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "User does not exist")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Login Error", "Please enter a username")
```

Comment: Does this code work? What's `userN`?

Comment: @200_success I left a lot of the code for the GUI elements out. The userN is the text from the user name text box of the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Encryption isn't Hashing

```
encryptedPass = hashPass(pW)
```

You're not encrypting the password, you're hashing it.

For passwords you should not be hashing them with the SHA2 family. Instead, use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

#### Sanitize input

From my limited knowledge of Python, it doesn't appear you're sanitizing your input on some functions, for example `userExists()` and the first query in `newUser()`. Instead, you're using simple string formatting to substitute values **directly**.

You should be passing the variables as arguments to [`execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) every time.

Comment: Thanks for the input! What's your thoughts on the way I am retrieving the key from the bin file and decrypting the server login credentials? Is this a secure way to store connection strings?

Comment: @Mr.clean I am not very familiar with Python. It looks _okay_, but security is very nuanced and I can't say for sure. Perhaps, if variables persist beyond the try-catch scope, you could `del` other variables used in it.

Comment: Please note that while bcrypt is better than plain SHA256 hashing (as is done now), Argon2 would be a more modern choice.

Comment: @SEJPM what’s your thoughts on my code from a security perspective? Also what makes sha256 insecure for password hashing?

Comment: @Mr.clean [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/71460) should explain password-hashing. It's a bit dated, so doesn't talk about Argon2 yet, but is otherwise really good. The only other interesting thing I could spot was the code putting the credential's key _unencrypted in a file right next to the ciphertext_.